# Check when SQL backup failes via Powershell

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, backup

Is it possible to capture info when the sql backup was run? And if the backup failed?
I use MSSQL and Powershell

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you information about backups including when it was last performed. It will not show if the backup failed, because failed backups are not listed as backups. You should find those in the job overview or history. If you use powershell, there will be no logging for a failed backup. (as far as I know)

This query is also used in Sequenchel(.com) for monitoring backups

```
SELECT isnull(y.server_name,CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS nvarchar(255))) as ServerName,
    x.name as databaseNameM, y.database_name as DatabaseNameB,
    CAST(DatabasePropertyEx(x.name,'Recovery') AS nvarchar(15)) as RecoveryModel ,
    case y.type 
        when 'D' then 'FULL BCK'
        when 'I' then 'DIFF BCK'
        when 'L' then 'TRAN BCK'
        when 'F' then 'FILE BCK' 
        else 'UNKNOWN!' 
    end as BackupType, 
    y.backup_finish_date as LastBackup,
    y.Bck_Location as Location
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases x
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT max_bck.server_name,max_bck.database_name,max_bck.backup_finish_date,max_bck.type,
    left(fam.physical_device_name,len(fam.physical_device_name)-patindex('%\%',reverse(fam.physical_device_name))+1) AS Bck_Location
FROM (select bak.server_name,bak.database_name,max(bak.backup_finish_date) as backup_finish_date,bak.type 
        from msdb.dbo.backupset bak
        group by bak.server_name,bak.database_name,bak.type) max_bck
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bak
ON max_bck.backup_finish_date = bak.backup_finish_date 
    and max_bck.type = bak.type
    and max_bck.database_name = bak.database_name
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily fam
ON bak.media_set_id = fam.media_set_id
) y
ON x.name = y.database_name
WHERE isnull(x.name,y.database_name) !='tempdb'
    AND (y.server_name IS NULL OR y.server_name = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS nvarchar(255)))
    AND CAST(DatabasePropertyEx(x.name,'Status') AS nvarchar(15)) = 'ONLINE'
ORDER BY ServerName,isnull(x.name,y.database_name),type
```